# I have a sequence which is made of complex exponentials with arbitrary amplitudes and initial phases. No noise

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have a sequence which is made of complex exponentials with arbitrary amplitudes and initial phases.  No noise.  That is it is a sum of the complex exponentials of the form $A_i e^{jnw_i+p_i}$.  For example, let us say i ranges from 1 to 10.  What is the minimum necessary data (number of samples) to calculate their amplitudes, initial phases and frequencies exactly i.e. $A$, $w$ and $p$ s?  And how can we find them? $j$ here is square root of -1 and $n$ is the sample number.

Comment: This looks like an application of [Prony's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method).